# filter Mongo collection by timeStamp filed

Tags: mongodb

I want to filter a mongo DB collection using creation time field and then return the first document.

I tried this

```
Document record = (Document) collection.find(and(eq("movie", "horror"), 
                 eq("creationTime", "$gte:ISODate('2020-04-22T16:02:18.843+00:00')"))).first();
```

Result from the above is Null

Expected result:

```
horror: Smile

creationTime: 2020-04-22T16:02:18.843+00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: Hi Ankit, record is null because of the creationTime argument and I'm sure how to fix it.

Comment: `eq` tests equality, so that query is looking for a document where `creationTime` is exactly the string `"$gte:ISODate('2020-04-22T16:02:18.843+00:00')"`